# Two hiddenlayer Neural Network is not working

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I already understand the concept of a single hidden layer neural network and now I'm trying to add another second hidden layer. I'm training the network not on a dataset, just one matrix X on the output y. But when I add a second hidden layer, the error doesn't decrease. Something might be wrong with the delta rule. Could you help me out?

```
import numpy as np

def nonlin(x, deriv=False):                 # sigmoid activation
    if deriv:
        return x * (1 - x)
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def relu(x, deriv=False):                   # relu activation
    if deriv:
        return 1/2 * (1 + np.sign(x))
    return x/2 + 1/2 * x * np.sign(x)

hiddensize_l1 = 8                              # amount of hiddennodes
hiddensize_l2 = 8
b = 1                                       # bias
lr = 10                                     # learning rate, gradient descent learn-step-size
dropout_percent, do_dropout = (0.3, True)

syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((3, hiddensize_l1)) - 1
syn1 = 2 * np.random.random((hiddensize_l1, hiddensize_l2)) - 1
syn2 = 2 * np.random.random((hiddensize_l2, 1)) - 1

X = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 0]])

y = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0]]).T

for i in range(10000):
    l0 = X

    l1 = relu(np.dot(l0, syn0) + b)

    l2 = relu(np.dot(l1, syn1) + b)

    l3 = nonlin(np.dot(l2, syn2) + b)

    l3_error = np.subtract(l3, y)
    l3_delta = l3_error * nonlin(l3, True)

    l2_error = np.dot(l3_delta, syn2.T)
    l2_delta = l2_error * relu(l2, True)

    l1_error = np.dot(l2_delta, syn1.T)
    l1_delta = l1_error * relu(l1, True)

    print(sum(l3_error) / len(l3_error))

    syn0 -= lr * (np.dot(l0.T, l1_delta))
    syn1 -= lr * (np.dot(l1.T, l2_delta))
    syn2 -= lr * (np.dot(l2.T, l3_delta))

print("Output After Training:")
print(l3)
```

Comment: The error does not shrink compared to the one hidden layer, or not at all during training?

Comment: Doesnt shrink at all. With one hidden layer i get perfekt outputs but with a second the output looks like this:
`Loss after  1 iterations:  [0.49999997] [...]
Loss after  1000 iterations:  [0.49999997]
Loss after  9994 iterations:  [0.49999997]
Loss after  9999 iterations:  [0.49999997]
Output After Training:
[[0.99999991]
 [0.99999999]
 [0.99999999]
 [0.99999999]]` @kutschkem

Comment: Please check the derivative of the sigmoid, I think it is incorrect.

Comment: So the derivitve of the sigmoid/s(x) is acutally  `s(x) * (1 - s(x))`, but i saw a lot of people (f.e. Trask) using `x * (1 -x)` and it is working fine. But maybe thats just fine for less layers. So i tried it now with the actual deriv but it returns me nans!

Comment: Ok the nans are just there because I set the learning rate to 10, which makes the numbers to high to enter the `np.sign` in the relu function, fixed it now. But the results remain the same. The loss is acutally decreasing but veeery low (like 8th decimal place). I tried to resize the layers and changed the lr but nothing worked. Is maybe the input to small for 2 hiddenlayers?

Comment: @kutschkem ok i got the mistake but it´s a little confusing:I when i change ONE component of the input from 0 to 1 it works. The net didnt like the input, but it seems that it is not very tolerant to different inputs, so thanks for your answers! :)